# hint and textview with right gravity and a singleline

Tags: android, textview, hint

I've opened a bug but i was wondering if anyone encountered this issue and knows a workaround.
If you define a text view with a hint inside it, give it right gravity (android:gravity="right") then if you define android:singleLine=true or android:maxLines="1" or android:scrollHorizonatally="true" you don't see the hint. removing the right gravity returns the hint to the left side, removing all the tree params i mentioned above puts the hint on the right side. i want my hint on the right, but i need a single horizontal line...

here's the sample layout that doesn't show the hint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">
            <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="6dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/c"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:hint="hello!!!"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

i checked on 1.6 and 2.1 emulators and it reproduces 100%, i'm prettysure it's a bug, i don't see the connection between single line and the hint.... what's more the hint got it's own layout in the TextView (mLayout and mHintLayout both exists, in onDraw if the text length is 0 mHintLayout if mHint is not null is used).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're exactly right with the issue; I tried playing with your example layout and saw the same issue.  I assume [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13895) is your bug report.

The easiest solution is to just change your layout, but that's probably not what you want to do.  My first attempt at a work around would be to try not setting any of those three attributes in XML and then setting them in Java.  If that doesn't work...

One option is to mimic the hint by either extending the EditText class and attempting to fix the code that lays out the hint yourself, or by overriding the onDraw method to create the hint, or perhaps by simply overlapping a regular TextView on top of the EditText, which you then show/hide manually.  You could even have the view check if it's empty, and if so set the text to your hint text and change the color.  When the view gains focus, check if its text is equal to your hint and, if so, remove the text and change the color back.

Another possible workaround that's a bit more "hacky" is to leave off the three attributes that cause problems, but try to manually prevent a newline from being created.  You'd need to create an OnKeyListener for your EditText, something like this:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // do nothing
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

You would also want to call `editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)` to avoid showing the return key.  It still may be possible to create a newline in your text field by pasting into it or perhaps some other method, so you would also want to parse and remove newlines when the form is submitted just to be safe.  This is also not likely to do what you want as far as horizontal scrolling.

Comment: i thought of extending as well.however since most of the internals of TextView and EditText are private i can't really touch them, so i'll have to creat my own hint member override setHint and setText so i can put the hint in my variable and display it in onDraw and once a click is made i need to remove it somehow. not a simple solution here....

Comment: this is no real solution ,I'll accept it anyway until something better will come up, the bug i opened for android was accepted and defined as NEW the bug is in the answer's link if any1 wants to follow

Answer (score 14):

Did you try `android:ellipsize="start"`? This has worked great for me in the past when I've wanted my hint and `EditText` to be centered.

Comment: Weird solution, but worked for me as well (had a TextView with right gravity, and textCapWords, and that was breaking the hint alignment). Thanks!

Comment: no problem, it definitely is an odd workaround, i have run into a large number of inconsistencies with `ellipsize`, `hint`, and `gravity`, maybe these will be cleaned up in the future

Comment: It works with textview right align,center vertical and singleline=true....Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

use these properties with hint and single line...u can chnge gravity!!

```
            android:gravity="right"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"             
            android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Noting worked good enough for me. When I set Gravity.right, the cursor was always on the right and couldn't be placed in the middle of the word.

I tried a different approach - put the set the gravity the the right  when there is no text (or left, if it works for you) and let android decide the best direction once the user entered something

This worked for me:

1. create `TextWatcher` class

   ```
   private static class FilterTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

       private WeakReference<Activity> mActivity;

       public FilterTextWatcher(Activity activity) {
           mActivity = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
       }

       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       }

       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
       }

       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           if (mActivity.get() == null)
               return;

           EditText searchTxtBx = mActivity.get().mSearchTxtBx;
           if (searchTxtBx.getText().toString().length() == 0)
               searchTxtBx.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
           else
               searchTxtBx.setGravity(0);
       }
   }
   ```
2. use it as class member

   ```
   private TextWatcher mFilterTextWatcher = new FilterTextWatcher(this);
   ```
3. in `onCreate()`:

   ```
   mSearchTxtBx.addTextChangedListener(mFilterTextWatcher);
   ```
4. in `onDestroy()`:

   ```
   mSearchTxtBx.removeTextChangedListener(mFilterTextWatcher);
   mFilterTextWatcher = null;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about my solution to this problem?

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus == false && StringUtils.isNotBlank(editText.getText().toString())) {
                editText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
        }
    });
```

And the corresponding XML File:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/the_text" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="number" android:hint="@string/edit_text_prompt"/>
```

Works fine for me: just one line, no enter-key possible, shows me the hint and when I leave the field after some input was given, the text appears right-aligned.

Comment: i need to check it with my code, but iusually don't like playing with focus listeners because focus is something that is usually gained in non-touch modes, except for things like EditText which is also fucusable in non touch mode... 10x anyway;-)

Answer (score 0):

it worked with me when I added:

```
android:hint="the hint text ..."
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="start"
```

and in my activity i added :

```
myedittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
          if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER&&event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    // do nothing
                    return true;
                }
          return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this issue when my TextView atrs are:

```
android:singleLine="true"  
android:gravity="right"
```

When I try to Linkify the textview or setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()) on that textview, the text is just gone.

```
android:ellipsize="start"
```

solved my issue, because I use Arabic text in my app.