# Android: Edittext with gravity center not working on device

Tags: android, android-edittext, gravity, text-cursor

In Android I'm using a single line edittext with gravity set to center. In the Emulator this works great both the hint and a blinking cursor shows up. When testing on device (Xperia X10) neither the hint text nor the blinking cursor shows up. The blinking cursor only shows if I enter some text into the edittext.

This is my edittext, can anyone see if something is missing?

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
>
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
    android:ellipsize="end" 
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:hint="Some hint text"
></EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I want:

[image: This is what I want]

What I get with the above code (empty edittext with no cursor):

[image: The edittext doesn't show the hint text and have no blinking cursor]

Comment: How were you able to get the style to be like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [hint and textview with right gravity and a singleline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649183/hint-and-textview-with-right-gravity-and-a-singleline)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I finally found the solution to get it working. This EditText works for me: (Tested on Sony Ericsson X10 and HTC Wildfire)

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
    android:digits="0123456789.,"
    android:ellipsize="start" 
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Some hint text"
></EditText>
```

Comment: I can't find the difference to th above one...?

Comment: I can't explain why we need that ellipsize, but we certainly do. that did it for me. thanks man.

Answer (score 6):

Hope it's not too late. I came across this problem and I don't know whether it is the same for every device but it appears `EditText` **by default has bottom padding**.

My EditText text value always appeared to be slightly above center despite setting gravity to be `CENTER` so I additionally set:

```
myEditText.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

This fixed it for me, now my EditText is perfectly centered :D

Comment: I just killed an hour working my way through this stupid issue. This worked, thanks!

I recommend myEditText.setPadding(myEditText.getPaddingLeft(), 0, myEditText.getPaddingRight(), 0); to maintain the left and right padding.

Answer (score 4):

i think , you should set the **gravity of the parentLayout** of your EditText , to **center**

**EDIT :**

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

   <EditText 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
       android:ellipsize="end" 
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:hint="Some hint text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested that but no difference. Please see the updated question.

Comment: see my edit too , i mean not to set the gravity of you editText , i said the gravity of his parentLayout ,

Comment: Yes I see, but that didn't make any difference. Is this working when you test on device?

Comment: remove the android:layout_gravity="center" and see whetherit works

Comment: @Martin , i will test it now in the emulator and in my device , you want it center Horizontal and vertical ? or just Horizontal ? , see my edit : (<EditText 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" )

Comment: Thanks but when testing your solution, I will get something like in this image: http://oi52.tinypic.com/16ifz20.jpg. So when you start typing the text will not be in center of the textfield. What I need is something like in the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a combination of gravities :

```
android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
```

My previous attempt was to nest the EditText inside a RelativeLayout and set it to center but it did not look that good , this way works best for me.

Answer (score 0):

- In XML file add gravity CENTER_HORIZONTAL for set hint to
  center.CURSORVISIBLE=false so cursor not visible when click first
  time
- In java use addTextChangedListener, when user add text that time
  change gravity to left and also visible cursor.

XML :

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/email"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:hint="EMAIL"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
  android:layout_margin="10dp"
  android:cursorVisible="false" />
```

JAVA:

```
email.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 

{

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.length() > 0) {
                    // position the text type in the left top corner
                    email.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP);
                    email.setCursorVisible(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    // no text entered. Center the hint text.
                    email.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    email.setCursorVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please consider explaining your solution a bit: what did you changed and why.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding the gravity in style tag add that inside your Layout file that will work

Comment: Thanks but that didn't do it. Please see the updated question.