# Can an EditText be focused without having the cursor in it?

Tags: android

When an EditText is focused, the cursor is visible in the text box.
Can I make it disappear?

Comment: you want like this:- http://stackoverflow.com/q/6136054/840861

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to disappear the edittext view ?

Comment: I want to make the cursor disappear

Comment: <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:cursorVisible="false">