# Hint text not able to see in Android version 2.3 but it works on 4.1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-styles

Hi am doing project with minimum sdk level 2.2
when i run my project on version 2.3 and keep my EditText gravity=center it not shows hint text in version 2.3 but it shows on 4.1

if i change EditText gravity from center to left i.e  gravity=left it works fine on all version

please help me out

Here is my XML code

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signin_btn_signin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/signinup_margin"
        android:background="@color/fent_green"
        android:text="@string/caption_signin"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/signin_et_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:layout_above="@+id/signin_btn_signin"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/signin_btn_signin"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/signin_btn_signin"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/signin_et_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:layout_above="@+id/signin_et_password"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/signin_et_password"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/signin_et_password"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/hint_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

Comment: `means hint text not able to see in version 2.3 it shows in 2.3 when component gravity is not centered if component gravity is "center" and version is 2.3 it not works please` can you try to rephrase this?

Comment: may be editext background color and hint text color is same.........

Comment: @njzk2 when i run my project on version 2.3 and keep my EditText gravity=center it not shows hint text in version 2.3 but it shows on 4.1

if i change EditText gravity from center to left i.e  gravity=left it works fine on all version

please help me out

Comment: @Shreeshesh
if color is same then how it will work 4.1 and not on 2.3??
any ways both color are contrans 
( its not same background is white and hint color is black )

Comment: for different versions style is different ....example for 2.3 edittext default background is white and for higher version background is transparent... so i told you.. :D

Comment: I think you have to change your android:inputType="textPassword" with   android:password="true"..Hope it helps you.

Comment: @Nil..
friend there are 2 edit text one is password one is email how can i give pssword 2 both edittext

i thik this
android:inputType="textPassword" with android:password="true".
 wil not a solution

anyways thanks for suggestion

Comment: I suggest you to do this in your first edittext and look that it is working or not..Anyways look into the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136054/android-edittext-with-gravity-center-not-working-on-device..hope wl help you.

Comment: @Nil..   hey boss thanks very much the link u gave me it works for me

Comment: @VikrantAlekar:-You are welcome dude..:)

Comment: Mark as accepted if the comment is useful.

Comment: @Nil.. its comment we can accept only post is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After researching and suggestions of all i got perfect answer
here am sharing my answer which will help others in future
Use this line in EditText properties

```
android:ellipsize="start"
```