# How can I set EditText cursor location at center where Hint is already populated?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a editTextbox as below and need to set cursor in the middle of it.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/my_custom_cursor"
    android:hint="Hello My World"/>
```

I tried:

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    int length = editText.getHint().length();
    editText.setSelection(length/2);  <-- problem
```

The length returns 0 since there is no real text exist in the editText box.
Could anyone tell me how I can set initial cursor locate at the middle of "Hello My World" ?

Thanks advance!

Comment: log the length, and see if its zero, if its not then it should work

Comment: cursor is already in middle

Comment: Your `hint` will keep changing or it is fixed one?

Comment: You can use `editText.setPadding (int left, int top, int right, int bottom);` if your `hint` is static.

Comment: yes, the length returns size of hint text but setSelection method doesn't see the same, e.g., it consider it as 0 length text populated. Apparently hint text is not same as regular text

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Hello My World"/>
```

Reference:

[Android: Edittext with gravity center not working on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136054/android-edittext-with-gravity-center-not-working-on-device)

Comment: I read this post before I tried but it didn't work.  The cursor stays the front of the text hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below if your `hint` is not dynamic.

```
 editText.setPadding (int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
```

Just give some int value to `left`, and the cursor will move.

Or you can add `android:paddingLeft="30dp"` to your `EditText` in xml file.

Comment: It not only moves entire hint text to the right by 30dp but also can't use the first 30dp on the left side.  What I need is just keep the cursor centered in the middle initially and as soon as user start typing, it starts from left 0dp area.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just add  request focus directly on your XML file. You don't have to do setting your cursor programmatically on your Activity.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Hello My World">

 <requestFocus />

</EditText>
```

If you don't add request focus on your EditText the cursor will not show unless you tapped on it. 
Hope this help.

Comment: I found no effect trying this

Comment: @beachboy what exactly you want to do with your edittext can you provide a screen shot?